# How to listen to events from outside my jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, events, plugins

My plugin takes some time doing something. So I want to listen to when the plugin is done with its task, from outside, so that I can display something.

I want to have something like this -

```
 $('li').filterGroup ({

        onInit: function(){
          alert("plugin has started working");
        },

        onComplete: function(){

          alert("plugin has finished");
        }
    })
```

I tried writing this inside my plugin code -

```
(function($) {
    // jQuery plugin definition

    $.fn.filterGroup = function(config) 
    {

        var settings = {
                    //some settings defined here
                        };




            var thisDropdown = this; //master  copy

        if(config)
        {
            $.extend(settings, config);
        }

            /*Tried following changes to make events work*/
            /*Tried following changes to make events work*/
            /*Tried following changes to make events work*/
            //I tried the following – assuming I will be able to listen to an onComplete event from outside

        // reference the function from the options passed
            var theFunc = config.onInit;
            var anotherFunc = config.onComplete;
            theFunc.call(); //does not work - gives error "theFunc is not a function"

        this.each(function() 
        {      
                    //here my plugin logic is done
            anotherFunc.call(); //this is also not working - "anotherFunc is not a function"
        });

        // allow jQuery chaining
        return thisDropdown;
    };
```

But this is not working, I am getting error -

```
theFunc is not a function
```

*Note -* I checked the PLugins authoring docs and specifically the events section http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Events, but looks like that is for defining public functions which can be called from outside, so not what I am looking for. Where is the original jquery doc for this? I think I just need to follow the docs properly.

Also checked the following questions but not getting -
[Bind Event to Custom Plugin Function in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983449/bind-event-to-custom-plugin-function-in-jquery)
[Custom Event For Custom JQuery Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930545/custom-event-for-custom-jquery-plugin)
[Handle events in a jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673803/handle-events-in-a-jquery-plugin)

**Update**

Okay, got my mistake, in my actual code I had `theFunc.call()` and `anotherFunc.call()` but in the calling part I had only handled `onComplete`. So, do I need to explicitly write the onInit() part in my plugin call -

This part -

```
onInit: function(){
              alert("plugin has started working");
            }
```

I mean if events are defined inside plugin, what if I don't want to handle in the outside code?

Comment: My advice is to use console.log in your code to see what's in config and what is actually the value of theFunc. Use Firebug or Chrome javascript console to see what's being logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange. It works for me.
http://jsfiddle.net/LHzjG/

BTW, you can also invoke the callbacks directly using `config.onComplete()` and put params if u like. And you can use `jQuery.isFunction()` to check if it's a function beforehand.